# How do I save the web service response to the same excel sheet I extracted the data from?

Tags: web-services, api, testing, qtp, hp-uft

For example:

The given sample HP Flights `SampleAppData.xls` and using the `CreateFlightOrder`, we can link the data to the test functions and get a `OrderNumber` and Price response from the Web Service. And in the `SampleAppData.xls` Input tab, we can see that there is a empty column of `OrderNumber`.

So here is my question, is there any ways that I can take the `OrderNumber` response and fill the empty column in `SampleAppData.xls`?

My point to do this is because, let's say I have many test cases to do and will take days, and today I do this certain test and I would need the result of today for the next day's test.

Although I know that the responses are saved in the result but it beats the point of automation if I am required to check the response for each and every test cases?

Comment: Don´t rely on readers to know the HP Flights sample. Better provide your own self-contained simple example. Then, we can precisely construct an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can. There are a number of ways to do this. The simplest is as follows.

```
'Datatable.Value("columnName","sheetName")="Value"
DataTable.Value(“Result”,”Action1”)=“Pass”
```

Once you have recorded the results in the Datasheet, your can export them using

```
DataTable.ExportSheet("C:\SavePath\Results.xls")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write back the response programatically , if you already imported mannually .

You can use GetDataSource Class of UFT API , it will work like this lets say you imported excel from FlightSampleData.xls, and named it as FlightSampleData, you have  sheet, accessing the sheet will be like below:

```
GetDataSource("FlightSampleData!input).Set(ROW,ColumnName,yourValue);
GetDataSource("FlightSampleData!input).Get(ROW,ColumnName);
```

for exporting you can use ExportToExcelFile method of GetDataSourse class after your test run . Please let me know if you have any furthur question about this.